# jni using NewDirectByteBuffer seeing random stuff in java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytebuffer

in my jni code I have

```
std::vector<uint32_t> vecIndices = sm->getIndices();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    printf("%i, ",vecIndices[i]);
}
printf("\n");
uint32_t* p = &vecIndices[0];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    printf("%i, ",p[i]);
}
printf("\n\n");

fflush(stdout);
jobject buff = env->NewDirectByteBuffer((void*)&p[0],sm->getNoOfIndices()*sizeof(uint32_t));

return buff;
```

when I use it in java like this:

```
    ByteBuffer ind = PVcore.meshGetIndices(mesh);
    IntBuffer indI= ind.asIntBuffer();

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        System.out.print(indI.get(i)+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int i=0;i<16;i++) {
        if (i % 4==0) System.out.println();
        System.out.print(ind.get(i)+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

I see this output:

```
 [java] 0, 2, 1, 1, 
 [java] 0, 2, 1, 1, 
 [java] 
 [java] 0, 0, -797764393, 117440512, 
 [java] 
 [java] 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 [java] 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 [java] -48, 115, 20, -41, 
 [java] 7, 0, 0, 0,
```

from the second line (0,2,1,1) I seem to have a contiguous set of values in a block of memory as expected from std::vector but giving this address to NewDirectByteBuffer and even looking at the byte values I seem to be getting odd values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<uint32_t> vecIndices` is removed from scope at the end of the function.

So the memory at `p` is no longer available to you.

Given that `NewDirectByteBuffer` does not take a deep copy of the array, `buff` will be referencing memory that you no longer own.

Comment: jobject buff = env->NewDirectByteBuffer((void*)&(sm->getIndices()[0]),sm->getNoOfIndices()*sizeof(uint32_t)); - seems to fix it - staring at that one for ages without seeing it!